# Custom Button , OnClick with PopupMenu

Tags: delphi, events, components

so I've created a custom Button based on cxButton . I wish to show a Popupmenu when I click this button . But for some reason the Popupmenu is not Showing up.
I don't even get a error , I have no idea why .

```
type
  TcxGridButton = class(TcxButton)
  private
    FGridView : TcxGridDBTableView;
    FPopup : TPopupMenu;

    procedure AutoSize(Sender : TObject);
    procedure ClearFilter(Sender : TObject);
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    constructor Create(AOwner : TComponent); override;

    procedure Click; override;
  published
    property GridView : TcxGridDBTableView read FGridView write FGridView;
  end;
```

And here is the Part where I Create the Popupmenu

```
constructor TcxGridButton.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
var Item : TMenuItem;
    P : TPoint;
begin
  inherited;

  Text:='Options';

  FPopup := TPopupMenu.Create(Self);

  Item := TMenuItem.Create(FPopup);
  Item.Caption:='Nach Excel exportieren';

  Item := TMenuItem.Create(FPopup);
  Item.Caption:='Automatische Größenanpassung';
  Item.OnClick:=AutoSize;

  Item := TMenuItem.Create(FPopup);
  Item.Caption:='Filter löschen';
  Item.OnClick:=ClearFilter;
end;
```

Now when I place this Button on the Form it has the Text Options displayed imediately so the Constructor seems to be running ok .

But when I click this button , I get the Click , Self.ToString and Done.
But the Popup menu never Pops up . What is my mistake ?

```
procedure TcxGridButton.Click;

begin
  inherited; // call the inherited Click method.

  ShowMessage('CLICK');

  if not Assigned(FGridView) then Exit;

  ShowMessage(Self.ToString);


  FPopup.Popup(0,0);


  ShowMessage('DONE');

end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple - you forgot to add the items to your popup menu:

```
{ after creating each item }
FPopup.Items.Add(Item);
```

In case you're not bound to `TCxButton` you can use standard VCL button that provides the functionality you're trying to implement via property [`Style`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomButton.Style) set to `bsSplitButton` and property [`DropDownMenu`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomButton.DropDownMenu). Otherwise you can at least study VCL's `TCustomButton` source code as an inspiration for your own implementation.

Comment: Thank you , unbelievable that I oversaw this :) Thank you - thank you - thank you!

Comment: I used cxButton , because I hook this Component up with a cxGrid , and there I do a few things which I do often. I just realized that I can create a component for this instead of writing code each and every time for three buttons